# How can you win a Fields Medal?

Tags: mathematics, awards

Consider someone who is pursuing a PhD in mathematics.

Is it possible for him/her to win the Fields medal?

To win a Fields medal, do you have to be an Assistant Professor?

What are some different ways through which you can win a Fields Medal?

Comment: It’s wide open, best of luck if that’s  a goal of yours.

Comment: I am somewhat reminded of the following story: *One man came to Mozart and asked him how to write a symphony. Mozart replied, “You are too young to write a symphony.” The man said, “You were writing symphonies when you were 10 years of age, and I am 21.” Mozart said, “Yes, but I didn’t run around asking people how to do it.”* (https://medium.com/@cdixon/one-man-came-to-mozart-and-asked-him-how-to-write-a-symphony-66e66eddd275)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You get a Fields Medal by publishing mathematics that is widely recognized as extremely significant. Grigori Perelman had no academic affiliation at the time of the award and at least one other recipient was in a research institute, but not an academic. No, you don't need to be an academic (and assistant professor isn't necessarily the first job in any case, depending on location).

I didn't look closely enough at the record to see if anyone has done the work as a student. but it shouldn't be hard to do as there aren't very many awards.

Yes, a grad student could do the necessary work, but it would be extremely unlikely, rare, and difficult. The Fields is awarded for "above and beyond" the normal scale of mathematical insight, captured in one or more significant publications.

It is about the math, not the person.

Answer (score 15):

It is indeed possible to do Fields medal-winning work as a PhD student. Two examples are [Manjul Bhargava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manjul_Bhargava), who won a Fields for his work on the parametrization of arithmetic objects and the geometry of numbers, and [Peter Scholze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Scholze), who won a Fields for his work on perfectoid spaces. In each case, much of the relevant work was done in graduate school.

However, each won their medal several years after finishing their PhD, after their work was published and widely read and appreciated by others, and after they further built on it and did further (spectacular!) work. This seems to be typical from what I can tell.

So, short answer, yes (if your thesis is *extraordinarily* good), but you'll probably end up graduating first. Incidentally, neither Bhargava nor Scholze was ever a tenure-track assistant professor; each was appointed a full professor at his PhD-granting institution soon after graduation.

Answer (score 8):

The [statutes](https://www.mathunion.org/fileadmin/IMU/Prizes/Fields/Statutes%20Fields%20Medal.pdf) of the prize are quite clear, and nowhere do they mention the need to be an assistant professor or to hold any academic job. (When Grigori Perelman was offered (and declined) the Fields medal in 2006, he had recently quit his research-only position at the Steklov Institute.) There is an age limit that might rule out some people pursuing a PhD:

> 2. The Fields Medal is awarded to an individual mathematician whose 40th birthday must not
>    occur before January 1st of the year of the ICM at which the Fields Medals are awarded.

However, realistically speaking, the bar to win one of the highest honors in a field is *very* high. A few great mathematicians meet it, but the vast majority do not. Note that there are at most four medals awarded every four years, whereas the number of math PhDs awarded each year in *just the US* is over 1200 according to the [AMS surveys](https://www.ams.org/profession/data/annual-survey/phds-awarded).

Comment: Only 1200? That's surprising low (to me), aren't there like a few thousand colleges in the US?

Comment: @BrtH The vast majority of colleges in the US do not have PhD programs in mathematics (or indeed in any field).

Comment: Why would the age limit rule out PhD students? While it is written in a particularly convoluted and confusing way, as far as I can tell that statute means that you cannot get  the medal if you are over 40, so only a very small proportion of PhD students would be affected. If anything, that makes it more likely that PhD students will get it, not less.

Comment: @terdon I didn't write it would rule out PhD students in general, just **some** PhD students. The clause does indeed mostly rule out older, more established folks, but those weren't the subject of the question.